# Testing Google App Engine apps

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am looking to see how others are testing their GAE apps. I've come across a few unit testing frameworks for python (green, pytest, nose, etc).

I then found the tutorial on the GAE site: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting and have been following that.

However, after doing what they say I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tests/test.py", line 2, in <module>
from google.appengine.ext import db
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

I am just running

```
python testrunner.py main/tests usr/local/google_appengine
```

from the terminal.

Any other ideas?

I have appengine in my pythonpath:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
-> /usr/local/google_appengine
```

Comment: nose+nosegae+nosy works great for me. `nosetests --with-gae --without-sandbox --gae-lib-root=/usr/local/google_appengine --with-path=.`

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?